# Data in QGIS getting deleted

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have been encountering an issue with QGIS that the data encoded on a layer connected to the database via PostGIS layers are getting deleted. It happened twice now.

Database is in pgAdmin4 and is operated in a local server. Saved data are deleted without any errors showing up.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Oh, my apologies :( Will take a look on that tour to fully understand how the site works. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds weird to me. Try to log all PostgreSQL queries https://stackoverflow.com/q/722221/930271 including the application ( https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html ) to help debug the issue. Are the data or the table deleted?

Comment: Can you add more info, what QGIS version and operating system  you are using?

Comment: The thing about databases is, they only delete what you DELETE (unless you never used COMMIT on the INSERT, in which case it was never inserted). I had a customer complain about a DELETE  taking a long time and deleting all rows; after getting custom debug libraries to trace his code, it turned out the code didn't apply a WHERE clause to the cursor object until after the DELETE was executed (ready, fire, aim).

Comment: Will try creating logs and it's just the data that are deleted. QGIS version is 2.18 Las Palmas and the operating system is Windows 10, i5 8th Gen processor and UHD Graphics 630. Will comeback after logging all PostgreSQL queries.